# Ordering WooCommerce Products by Meta Field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, sql-order-by

Each of my products has a special meta field (a timestamp). I'd like to order my products on all pages by this timestamp.

Here is the code that is currently in my functions file. The products do not re order.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'mind_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
function mind_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $query ) {
    if(!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key','_start_date' );
        $query->set( 'orderby','meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order','DESC' );
    }
}
```

I've confirmed that each post does have a '_start_date' meta field.

Is there a woocommerce setting that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot.

```
function custom_add_postmeta_ordering_args( $sort_args ) {

    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    switch( $orderby_value ) {

        // Name your sortby key whatever you'd like; must correspond to the $sortby in the next function
        case '_start_date':
            $sort_args['orderby']  = 'meta_value';
            // Sort by meta_value because we're using alphabetic sorting
            $sort_args['order']    = 'desc';
            $sort_args['meta_key'] = '_start_date';
            // use the meta key you've set for your custom field, i.e., something like "location" or "_wholesale_price"
            break;

    }

    return $sort_args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_add_postmeta_ordering_args' );
// Add these new sorting arguments to the sortby options on the frontend
function custom_add_new_postmeta_orderby( $sortby ) {

    // Adjust the text as desired
    $sortby['_start_date'] = __( 'Sort by start date', 'woocommerce' );

    return $sortby;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_add_new_postmeta_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_add_new_postmeta_orderby' );
```

Comment: Thanks! I found the problem was actually being caused because I'm using Facet WP to filter. So, I opted to simply remove the wooCommerce sorting and add the Facet WP sorting. Keeps it all under one roof, as it were. 

However, I did test your code and it works great! Thank you!